# Malsup form upload stuck at percentComplete==100 (bootstrap progress upload)

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm working on uploading files base on malsup codes. I adapted code from [DANIEL MORGAN's File Upload Progress Twitter Bootstrap PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMo1Y.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMo1Y.png): http://www.danmorgan.net/programming/file-upload-progress-twitter-bootstrap-php/.

The upload process is work just fine. But when the upload is complete / when the percentComplete==100. The upload has frozen and the progress bar keep running as active.

**JS**

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ajaxUpload').ajaxForm( {
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $(this).addClass('loading');
        //$('#uploadBox').html('<div id="progressOverlay"><div class="progress progress-striped"><div class="bar" id="progressBar" style="width: 0%;">0%</div></div></div>');
        $('#uploadBox').html('<div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"><span class="sr-only">0%</span></div></div>');
    },
    uploadProgress: function ( event, position, total, percentComplete ) {
        if (percentComplete == 100) {
            $('#progressBar').css('width',percentComplete+'%').html('Processing...');
        } else {
            $('#progressBar').css('width',percentComplete+'%').html(percentComplete+'%');
        }
    },
    success:function(json){
        if(!json.error) location.reload(true);//refresh after ajax call succeed
        //$('#ajaxUpload')[0].reset();//reset form after uploaded
    }
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="ajaxUpload" class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="inc/eval_uploader.php">
<input type="hidden" name="evl_sid" value="$rec_sStd[std_sid]" />
<input type="hidden" name="evli_sid" value="$rec_sStdi[stdi_sid]" />
<div id="uploadBox"></div><!-- /uploadBox -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only">uploader</label>
    <input type="file" class="hide" name="upl" id="upl" onchange="$(this.form).submit();"/>
    <input type="text" name="floc" id="floc" size="5" class="form-control width-auto" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off" placeholder="เช่น 217" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  onClick="$('#upl').click();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;เลือกไฟล์ & อัพโหลด</button>                  
</div><!-- /form-group -->              
</form>
```

Now I need to know why it being stuck with loading progress. And would be a huge appreciate if you can give me a clue of displaying file uploaded to be displayed in div#uploadBox.

**Screen Capture**

[image: malsup frozen at percentComplete==100]

Regards,

Comment: And what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

What about the 'complete' method?
I just put a sample of the jquery form plugin in the jsbin, take a look [here](http://jsbin.com/xetuguje/1/edit?html,output)...

Here is your script + the 'complete' method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ajaxUpload').ajaxForm( {
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $(this).addClass('loading');
        //$('#uploadBox').html('<div id="progressOverlay"><div class="progress progress-striped"><div class="bar" id="progressBar" style="width: 0%;">0%</div></div></div>');
        $('#uploadBox').html('<div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"><span class="sr-only">0%</span></div></div>');
    },
    uploadProgress: function ( event, position, total, percentComplete ) {
        if (percentComplete == 100) {
            $('#progressBar').css('width',percentComplete+'%').html('Processing...');
        } else {
            $('#progressBar').css('width',percentComplete+'%').html(percentComplete+'%');
        }
    },
    success:function(json){
        $('#progressBar').css('width','100%').html('Upload complete...');
        //if(!json.error) location.reload(true);//refresh after ajax call succeed
        //$('#ajaxUpload')[0].reset();//reset form after uploaded
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        //You can use here to do whatever you want with the progress bar

        //This show the file uploaded
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
</script>
```

Add the status div in your html:

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: The upload still freeze at "processing..." Be advised.

Comment: What about you put the html of the progress bar (using the same structure i send in the sample) in the page instead of add dinamically? Maybe change your code to work like the example.

Comment: I already did, pecci. But it stuck for no reason. I tried to inspect the error in firebug but nothing error.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend another jQuery file upload tool, http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/.
There are some good solutions to upload files with jQuery https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/js. Fortunately, this is also built with Bootstrap CSS framework and Glyphicons. But the MOST important thing is that progress bars work efficiently.

I got the same problem with you. After the progress bar reached 100%, it would cost two more seconds or so to display results. In other words, function of `success` in `.ajaxForm` would be called about two seconds after function of `uploadProgress` completed.

Wish it could be helpful.